# 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component. Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is how _app.tsx looks:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

and I am getting this error while building project:

```
Type error: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/user/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

These are the react versions:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"@types/react": "17.0.26",
```

I tried to switch to 18 version, it worked but, I got this error: `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server`

Comment: What are you passing in to the `Component` prop?

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean about this: `{...pageProps}`?

Comment: Make sure that the page you're trying to render is a valid React component. Keep in mind `Component` in this context is your page component, so it's saying that your page component is not a valid React component.

Comment: No, I mean what are you passing to `MyApp` as the `Component` prop.

Comment: @DaveNewton if I correctly understood you, then I am not passing any prop to `MyApp`, because nextjs does passing something, I don't know what. It's the _app.tsx file

Answer (score 5):

**Add the following code into `package.json` file**

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2"
}
```

**Then Reinstall the packages**

```sh
yarn
```

- if using npm

```sh
npm i
```

Answer (score 3):

Update React types to 18 in devDependencies (If you use already 17.x):

```
"@types/react": "^18",
"@types/react-dom": "^18"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, update @types/react and @types/react-dom resolves the problem.

```
yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you did not set typescript properly in your project. I think, currently, when you install next.js, you should have option to select `typescript`. If not

```
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node.
```

in tsconfig.json, you should have  `"jsx": "preserve"` in compiler options. It allows us to use .tsx files in the project. an example of tsconfig.json

- I think this might be the issue. In order to indicate that we are returning `jsx` we have to wrap the component with `()`. but in your component you have

  ```
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
  ```

even though I tried to put `()`, vscode omits it. So try arrow function:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => (
  <Component {...pageProps} />
);

export default App;
```

Comment: typescript installed correctly because I created the project like this: `yarn create next-app --typescript`

Comment: can you try the options that I passed.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately getting the same error :( [this](https://postimg.cc/yJJcGhYW) is how IDE marks the error

Comment: @ОвовОчоы I updated the answer. I think found the issue

Comment: Still getting that error :((( I don't know why this error happens with version 17 of react 
it wasn't like this before

Comment: do u have github repo. i got curioous

Comment: I switched to version 18.0.6 of @types/react and got rid of the error, thank you for your helping anyway!